# error in python when running code TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: python

whenever i run my program, it throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\steam\Desktop\TikTok-Caption-Generator-main\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from modules.captions import transcribe_audio
  File "C:\Users\steam\Desktop\TikTok-Caption-Generator-main\modules\captions.py", line 4, in <module>
    import whisper
  File "C:\Users\steam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\whisper.py", line 69, in <module>
    libc = ctypes.CDLL(libc_name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\steam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 369, in __init__
    if '/' in name or '\\' in name:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

i dont know. I tried again and again, but it dod not change.

Comment: Where did `name` get defined? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The error message implies `libc_name` is `None` and it is an error with importing `whisper`, whatever that is.